# Flutter: Why my SharedPreferences is not working?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

many thanks for helping me!
I am learning Flutter, and I have encountered a problem: My SharedPreferences is not working when I close my app and open it again (it is just the default counter app).
Here is my code:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadScore();
  }

  void _loadScore() async {
    final SharedPreferences scoreData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _score = scoreData.getInt('score') ?? 0;
    });
   }

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    final SharedPreferences scoreData = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
       _score = (scoreData.getInt('score') ?? 0) + 1;
       scoreData.setInt('score', _score);
   });
   }
```

Comment: add the code where u put data to sharedprefrences

Comment: your code work fine

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to paste your complete code as its not completed yet. but I got your code and I saw this code is working. I will paste my full code maybe it will be helpful for you

```
import 'package:bloc_test/utils/extention.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class TestSharedPref extends StatefulWidget {
  TestSharedPref({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestSharedPref> createState() => _TestSharedPrefState();
}

 class _TestSharedPrefState extends State<TestSharedPref> {
  int? _score;
  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
    _loadScore();
  }

   void _loadScore() async {
    final SharedPreferences scoreData = await 
 SharedPreferences.getInstance();
     setState(() {
       _score = scoreData.getInt('score') ?? 0;
     });
   }

   void _incrementCounter() async {
    final SharedPreferences scoreData = await 
SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
       _score = (scoreData.getInt('score') ?? 0) + 1;
       scoreData.setInt('score', _score ?? 0);
    });
  }

   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       body: Container(
         child: Center(
            child: Column(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
             children: [
                Text("Counter Value : $_score"),
                ElevatedButton(
                 onPressed: () {
                    _incrementCounter();
                  },
                     child: Text("Increment"),
               )
              ],
            ),
         ),
        ),
      );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?